# 12 images in a grid. Random order and given size

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image, random, grid

I'm making a image grid of 12 images of 3 given sizes.

- 1080x320
- 720x320
- 320x320

Basic view of the grid can be seen in the following illustration:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdws9.png

I want the layout to be able to change it's pattern, like the second image.

But also making the images change position and size, like the third image in the gallery.

- All of the 12 images must be shown.
- The layout can be changed, ex. 12 1080x320 boxes or 12 320x320 boxes or 6 720x320 and 6 320x320 boxes

I've been searching Google, but can't find a Wordpress plugin or jQuery plugin that fit my needs.
Do you have some ideas to my problem? Ideas of solutions and so on. All tips are very much welcome.

Comment: er... just some math and some work ethic. put them in 3 media query.

Comment: Use [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/. It's responsive and pretty easy to use.